# save a string as a JSON in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to save JSON in a Django field like following:

```
{
    "first_name": "bgbg",
    "last_name": "hbbgh",
    "username": "reza",
    "user_profile": {
        "id": "1ac3ca9c-563e-4f78-b9fa-01552a30585d",
        "gender": "M",
        "birthday": "2015-09-04",
        "country": "Iran",
        "city": "Tehran",
        "street_address": "dsafrfl",
        "state": "dskj",
        "about": "fdgrdshrbfr",
        "social_links": {"linkedin": "http://linkedin.com"},
        "location": "11,22",
        "avatar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/user/1ac3ca9c-563e-4f78-b9fa-01552a30585d/avatar/1ac3ca9c-563e-4f78-b9fa-01552a30585dBooking.gif",
        "verification_code": "9469"
    }
```

But social_links saves like:

```
"social_links": "{\"linkedin\": \"http://linkedin.com\"}",
```

**I'm using Django REST framework**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_image_path)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    social_links = JSONCharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking at an unescaped string in a debugger?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean to say?

Comment: Can you save as text field and return the response as return Response(json.loads(social_links), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Comment: That string is correct. There is no problem here.

Comment: @Geo Jacob, It sounds good, and I think I use this way, but Can I save a string without slash and " like an JSON in a field?

Comment: @altruistic If you use JSON field you can save the string without slash. I'm using `jsonfield library` to save json data in project.

Comment: How are you passing your data into that JSON field?

Comment: I got it! Now I know what i should do. {"linkedin": "http://linkedin.com"}

Answer (score 0):

You should **parse you json data** then save with (objects.create) command .

Also you can use "Django rest-framework" Serializers.